# Keep getting RunDLL error on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, rundll

This error keep popping up on my screen even though I do nothing. It just pop up at anytime! This error appears since I run virus scan + remove threat on AVG Internet Security 2015. After that I uninstall the program...

What do I need to do to get rid of this annoying error?

[image]

Comment: This indicates you did not fully remove an infection.  Can you please upload the image to the stackexchange image host instead?  Be sure you check out these existing questions [this](http://superuser.com/questions/561016/rundll-error-hard-disk-drive?rq=1) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/547209/rundll-wont-stop-popping-up?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry, did you mean remove thread or remove threat. I assume threat but should ask. If you've had a virus, nuke the machine. Remember, you may have removed the infection, but, the damage it did has not neccessarily been undone!

Comment: What program is it that you uninstalled? Anyway, if you have confirmed that you had contracted malware, the safest approach is to backup user files, and rebuild the sysetm. There is simply no way to be sure its clean ever again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: As I suspect.  Just extrapolate [this](http://superuser.com/questions/561016/rundll-error-hard-disk-drive?lq=1) answer for `SysMenu.dll` and your problem will be solved.